# How should I translate 彼が即死した?

Tags: grammar

即死 is a noun with meaning "instant death" and the grammar

> S＋が/は＋Ｎ＋する

as far as I know, means someone does something. For example,

- 僕は勉強する。I study.
- 彼がテニスする。He plays tennis.

Now, if I apply the noun 即死, for example,

- 彼が即死した。

Which is the correct translation?

- He died instantly. (my translation)
- He was killed instantly. (google's translation)

I don't understand why google used passive form here.

Comment: It seems the both are used. http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8D%B3%E6%AD%BB&ref=sa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Google preferred "to be killed" because 即死 is usually used with sudden physical accidents like a car crash, lightning strike, explosion, gun shot, etc. Take a look at [examples sentences here](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E5%8D%B3%E6%AD%BB). In English, "to be killed" is frequently used with those (maybe more often than "to die of"?), while 殺される in Japanese is basically only for murder cases.

It's safe to use 即死 with, for example, a sudden heart attack, but it's less common.